# Network output from server can't be read by client

Tags: java, network-programming

So, I have a simple socket server and a socket. I run the socket server, successfully. The client socket connects and sends a string - this works. I want the server to write back different information based on this string. I can check what the string is and get an OutputStream to the client, but whenever I write to it and flush, the InputStream client-side is NEVER in a ready state, and will never get a message back... I just don't see what I'm doing wrong.

All the code is at http://pastebin.com/u/omegazero

NetworkAgent.java is the client, SimbadAgent.java is the server, and UserAgent.java is the actual implementation of said server (the server is abstract for other reasons).

Compile everything, then run UserAgent followed by NetworkAgent and you will see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executed your code (after commenting the reference to StringQueue in SimbadAgent) and I got the following output.

```
wrote get_cmd
Input shutdown? false
iS()iI()iM()iB()iA()iD()i ()iB()iO()iO()iY()iA()NETWORKAGENT: Response to "get_cmd": "SIMBAD BOOYA"
```

Comment: Wait... really? I'll have to test it on a different OS... maybe it's my Debian setup or something weird. Thanks.

Comment: It was actually because I had to switch them over to PrintWriter and BufferedReader, if anyone reads this eventually. Java is fickle about character streams apparently..